# Wrong result with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a script to get some posts from a database.
Here is the script:

```
private function getItems()
    {
        $this->dbConnect($detailsTable);
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
        mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
        mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * 
        FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships,wp_term_taxonomy 
        WHERE wp_posts.post_status = "publish"  
        AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = id
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy= "category"
        AND !(wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 11)
        AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 25', LINK);
        mysql_close(LINK);

        $items = '';
        while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $title = UTFayar($row['post_title']);
            $content = UTFayar($row['post_content']);

            $items .= '<item id="'.$row["ID"].'">
                <title><![CDATA['.$title.']]></title>
                <description><![CDATA['. $content .']]></description>
                <pubDate>'.date('D, j M Y H:i:s T', strtotime($row['post_date'])).'</pubDate>
                <category>'.$row['post_category'].'</category>
            </item>';
        }
        $items .= '</channel>
                </rss>';

        return $items;
    }
```

The problem is that some posts are in 3+ categories.
So I get a wrong result, I get same post 3+ times successively. I need that this post even if is at more then one category to be showed in my rss only 1 time.

EIDTED:

Here is right code, if some one will need it:

```
    private function getItems()
    {
        $this->dbConnect($detailsTable);
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
        mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
        mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
        //$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status="publish" and post_category!=17 and post_category!=18 ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 20', LINK);
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT 

ID
, post_title
, post_content
, post_date
, group_concat(DISTINCT post_category ORDER BY post_category DESC SEPARATOR ", " ) as "categories"

FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships,wp_term_taxonomy 
        WHERE wp_posts.post_status = "publish"  
        AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = id
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy= "category"
        AND !(wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 11)
        AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        GROUP BY ID, post_title, post_content, post_date ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 25', LINK);
        mysql_close(LINK);
        $items = '';
        while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $title = UTFayar($row['post_title']);
            $content = UTFayar($row['post_content']);



            $items .= '<item id="'.$row["ID"].'">
                <title><![CDATA['.$title.']]></title>
                <description><![CDATA['. $content .']]></description>
                <pubDate>'.date('D, j M Y H:i:s T', strtotime($row['post_date'])).'</pubDate>
                <category>'.$row['categories'].'</category>
            </item>';
        }
        $items .= '</channel>
                </rss>';

        return $items;
    }
```

Comment: is `$detailsTable` defined somewhere?

Comment: Don't your posts have a common unique id?  It looks like your posts are going into different tables (bad) when they should all be in the same table with a column describing what type of category they are.

Comment: `LINK` is a constant referring to the MySQL connection, right?  According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/define), you shouldn't do that.  `It is possible to define resource constants, however it is not recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior.`

Comment: yes yes, every thing is declared. and the rss works perfectly , just the result is wrong if the same post is at more then one category. thanx

Comment: Also, don't use the `@` operator, if there's an error, you should fix it, not ignore it.

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestions. the point is that i get a duplicated post if the post is in more then one category.. can some one help please.

Comment: What is the structure of the `wp_posts`, `wp_term_relationships`, and `wp_term_taxonomy` tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to deal with the categories in some way.... rolling them up and displaying them in a list with commas may be a good way to deal with it.

mysql has a nice function called "GROUP_CONCAT" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

your query would be

```
    SELECT 

    ID
    , post_title
    , post_content
    , post_date
    , group_concat(DISTINCT post_category ORDER BY post_category DESC SEPARATOR ', ' ) as `categories`

    FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships,wp_term_taxonomy 
            WHERE wp_posts.post_status = "publish"  
            AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = id
            AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy= "category"
            AND !(wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 11)
            AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
GROUP BY    ID
    , post_title
    , post_content
    , post_date             
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: in the bottom you would need to change it from $row['post_category'] to  $row['categories']

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in <b>D:\database\xampp\htdocs\gen\index.php</b> on line <b>65</b><br />

Comment: you get it with the query? I will check it, but i do not have your db.... GROUP_CONCAT may need to be capitolized

Comment: no thats not right, mysql_query() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in ... can you post code again... something is wrong

Comment: put single quotes for the separator (this may not be the issue ,but documentation uses single quotes)

Comment: u can escape the single quote with a "\'" or change query to use double quotes....

Comment: there is no more error, just now i get some posts that are not  the latest one, and is only 1 post there..

Comment: oh i forgot something hold on!

Comment: above the order by put "group by ID, post_title, post_content, post_date"

Comment: thats the issue, i am sure of it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4519/discussion-between-matthewhall58-and-meo)